# error MSB4025: The project file MyProject.csproj could not be loaded. '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, active-directory, samba

**My programming environment:**
I work on a Windows client that is a member of an AD domain. The Windows profile (C:\Users...) and the home directory are stored on a Debian server that serves as a file server. The Windows profile is regularly synchronized with the server at logon and logoff. Samba is used as the AD domain controller. I am responsible for creating and compiling .NET5 projects using the Visual Studio Code IDE.

**My problem**
I create projects on the local Windows profile C:\Users\Username\projects using the dotnet new console statement. The statement creates a C# project with .csproj file. I call the file MyProject.csproj for better understanding. There are usually no problems when compiling. Now when I log off the local windows profile is synchronized with the server. If I now log in somewhere else and want to compile the project again, the error message **"error MSB4025: The project file MyProject.csproj could not be loaded. '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 9, position 11."** is displayed.
If you open the project file, you can see that the value NUL was written in line 9 an infinite number of times (see attached picture).

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: If you delete those characters in your text editor, do they come back later?

Comment: If I log in to a client I have never logged in to before, there is a high probability that this error will occur again. Characters of this type also occur in other project files. Sometimes a json file is affected, sometimes a .csproj.

Comment: The problem definitely has something to do with BOM:
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.de.html.